# Unable to Paste Text From Excel VBA Editor to MS Edge

Tags: excel, copy-paste, microsoft-edge, vba

I often copy text from Excel's VBA editor (Immediate Window).  Generally, I'm formatting [SQL](http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm?ref=wangz.sqlformat.htm) .  It won't paste.  Every other browser works fine.  I find this absurd.  Paste from an MS product to an MS product doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can verify what you have found.

To get around this behavior:

- copy from the VBA editor either with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd> or the Menu
- paste into NotePad
- copy from NotePad
- paste into Edge

```
Sub hello()
    MsgBox "Hello World"
End Sub
```

*(I have not determined if this is Microsoft's way of discouraging the use of Edge or encouraging the use of NotePad)*